# HTACCESS Redirecting from url with query string, to the same url with query string + string

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to take a url with a query string and redirect it back to the same url with query string but with an added string.

Trying to get the following to work I have tried everything I could find but ran into issues along the way, not sure it's possible at this point. There are possibly 50-100 versions of the inventory query.

Current Urls:

www.somecompany.com/inventory?type=new

www.somecompany.com/inventory?type=used

Desired Redirects:

www.somecompany.com/inventory?type=new&view=grid

www.somecompany.com/inventory?type=used&view=grid

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^inventory$ inventory%1&view=grid
```

My closest result was a loop error which makes me think that what I'm trying to do isn't possible. But hoping it is.

Comment: You need to check for the query param in `RewriteCond` first. Otherwise it will result in a redirect loop, because you are redirecting the URLs to themselves for each request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)view= [NC]
RewriteRule ^inventory$ inventory?view=grid [QSA,NC,L,R=301]
```

This is the `QSA` (Query String Append) indication that automatically does the work of adding the old parameters to the new ones.

If you want to rewrite it and not redirect it, just delete the flag `,R=301`.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work, as is just didn't work, once I removed the R=301, the site pages were working as normal but without adding the &view=grid to the end of the url